# Facebook API | Redirect After Delete Comments

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

**The Scenario**

I am making a Facebook app and got to the point where I can **successfully** delete comments using the latest version of the graph api.

**The Problem**

after I make a successful delete request it keeps me on the page and displays "success:true", I want to know if there is a way to redirect back to my website after the request is completed. I can't seem to find it anywhere so any information (accurate) will be useful.

Comment: you can try a header http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php or a meta refresh. I'm pretty sure Facebook has a redirection callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a solution, it was quite a long shot to be honest but somehow it worked really lucky guess.

```
    public function getFB()
{
    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '1465585287079663',
        'app_secret' => '89a628f5bf65b4cb6c5f867e4eede549',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.4'
    ]);
    return $fb;
}
```

The above code sets the FB variable to allow me to use the various FB methods.

```
    public function deleteComment($id)
{
    $fields = Page::where('id', 1)->get();

    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        $pageToken = $field->page_access_token;
    }

    try{
        $this->getFB()->delete("/$id", ['method' => 'delete', 'access_token' => $pageToken]);
    }catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e){
        exit;
    }

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

The above code lets me get the access token from the database, then delete the ID that i want deleting and redirects me back to the previous page.